# How to select using script on Task Scheduler the "run with highest privileges"

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript

Hi I'm doing some scripting to add a task on a Task Scheduler. However I need to have a script to select the "run with highest privileges".

Sample code:

```
Dim settings
Set settings = taskDefinition.Settings
settings.Enabled = True
settings.StartWhenAvailable = True
settings.Hidden = False
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `vbscript` instead of the `schtasks.exe` or `PowerShell`?

Comment: Nothing, I just started usung vbscript

Comment: @JoshZhang is it possible in vbscript?

Comment: While it's possible to do with vbscript, I can't find the documentation for highest privileges flag, plus it is **much** easier to accomplish this using PowerShell or even schtasks.exe.

Comment: @JoshZhang can you give me a sample of it on powershell?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with the `-RunLevel Highest` flag for `New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal` in PowerShell.

Example:

```
# Set the scheduled task time and repitition
$TaskTime = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 12:00

# Set  the task to run as a local administrator with highest level privileges
$TaskUser = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupId "BUILTIN\Administrators" -RunLevel Highest

# Set actions the schedule task should perform
$Action1 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "chrome.exe"
$Action2 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "notepad.exe"

# Registers the task with Task Scheduler
Register-ScheduledTask "Test Scheduled Task" -Action $Action1,$Action2 -Principal $TaskUser
```

[PowerShell ScheduledTask documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=windowsserver2019-ps).